# Python: math.pow() vs **?

Tags: python, pow

I tried a code:

`print(int((9 ** 29) + (7 ** 27)))`

Answer: `4710194409608608369201743232` and

`print(int(math.pow(9,29) + math.pow(7,27)))`

Answer: `4710194409608608302099333120`

And both gave me a different answer. Why is that?

Comment: It might have something to do with the fact that math.pow converts it's arguments to floats and also outputs a float. Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.pow